# COALESCE in oracle sql not behaving as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, coalesce

I recently had a question answered on how to update table A's column B with values from table C's column D, respective to id's.

```
UPDATE Table2 t2
    SET D_N = COALESCE( (SELECT t1.D_N FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.D_ID 
= t2.D_ID), 0);
```

The code worked and now I'm trying to do the same, only the comparison isn't done on `VARCHAR/VARCHAR2` fields but `NUMBER`. The fields i'm referring to are `D_ID`. The code worked on `VARCHAR2/VARCHAR` fields and now these are `NUMBER`.

I thought this would be easy to fix, so i created a temp column for each table and filled it with the values with the `to_char` method and my schema shows as expected, a column with data type `VARCHAR2` for both Table1 and Table2 columns `D_ID`.

I still receive the error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER` though.

DDL for tables in question:

```
CREATE TABLE  "Table1" 
   (    
    "D_ID" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "D_N" VARCHAR2(30) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP" CONSTRAINT "D_N_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TEMPDEPTID" VARCHAR2(4) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
     CONSTRAINT "D_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("D_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP"
/
ALTER TABLE  "Table1" ADD CONSTRAINT "D_L_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("L_ID")
      REFERENCES  "Table3" ("L_ID") ENABLE
/
ALTER TABLE  "Table1" ADD CONSTRAINT "D_M_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("M_ID")
      REFERENCES  "Table2" ("E_ID") ENABLE
/


CREATE TABLE  "Table2" 
   (    
    "D_ID" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "TEMPDEPTID" VARCHAR2(4) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
    "D_N" VARCHAR2(30) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMP_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("E_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 

   )  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP"
/
ALTER TABLE  "Table2" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_D_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("D_ID")
      REFERENCES  "Table1" ("D_ID") ENABLE
/
ALTER TABLE  "Table2" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_M_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("M_ID")
      REFERENCES  "Table2" ("E_ID") ENABLE
/
```

Thanks.

Comment: Updating now, thanks

Comment: The issue here might also be the two `D_N` columns, _not_ the `D_ID` columns.  Tough to say without seeing table definitions, which you still have not included :-)

Comment: Took some time but they're here :) thanks for bearing with me

Comment: To be honest, you should not be getting this error AFAIK if these table definitions are current.

Comment: that's what I thought.. and yeah the definitions are right. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The 0 at the end of the COALESCE was causing this it seems,

```
UPDATE Table2 t2
    SET D_N = COALESCE( (SELECT t1.D_N FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.D_ID 
= t2.D_ID), 0);
```

changed to

```
UPDATE Table2 t2
    SET D_N = COALESCE( (SELECT t1.D_N FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.D_ID 
= t2.D_ID), '-');
```

did it for me.